# jQuery error "C is undefined" while making ajax call for pagination

Tags: 6, javascript, paging

I am using Ajax for pagination for a form in Drupal 6 project. It is working fine on my local machine with default theme but on live server it gives me an error and generates another pagination links below original one.

When I click on Next, Previous or page link it gives me an error "c is undefined
http://siteurl/sites/default/files/js/js_2ebf7f4036f86f9133a99317ed832acf.js/eval/seq/1
Line 1". Every time I click on link, it gives me the same error.

I have searched for some solutions, like http://drupal.org/node/846026, but they are not useful

Comment: Does it work if you clear cache?  Does it work if you turn of Javascript aggregation?  Are there any errors in the status report?

Comment: No every time I change the code, I used to clear cache and there are some javascript warnings

Answer (score 1):

Finally I fixed it. But I think there should be better way of doing that. All I did was, I added latest jQuery file from Google CDN in the module itself as it was clashing with Drupal 6 dynamically added jQuery 1.2.x and giving me error.

```
 drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/my_module.js');
```

I used some ajax calls for pagination, due to which old jQuery was giving me an error. It is fixed with newer version of jQuery. I also tried http://drupal.org/node/1058168 but it was also not useful.

Please suggest if there is any better way of doing the same.

Comment: Updating jQuery is tricky; it has a bad habit of breaking admin feaures.  Take a look at the jQuery Update and jQuery Multi modules.  The later is my preferred method nowadays.